# Submitting various sitemaps for different languages

Tags: sitemap, google-index

i have a site translated into 4 languages.
I have submitted the sitemap to google webmaster tools (GWT) as one sitemap and translation links like below:
[image]

I got a recommendation to create different properties for each language and submit a sitemap for each property in GWT. in other words to create property of https://www.example.com/de and to submit a sitemap for German content and the same applies for Fr, Ar, and En.
**The reason to do this is to speed up the indexing process on google, does this make any sense?**

Comment: Sitemaps don't usually help get your site crawled or indexed.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)